# Как вызвать async функцию внутри потока?

Tags: python

```py
import some_lib
import Thread from threading
async def function():
    x = ""
    # do some stuff with x
    await some_lib.asyncFunction(x)
async def ThreadFunction():
    while(1):
        condition = some_lib.getSomething()
        if(condition()):
            await function()
MyThread = Thread(target=ThreadFunction)
MyThread.start()
some_lib.DoOtherStuff()
```

```
RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'MainThreadFunction' never awaited
```

Как исправить этот код ?

Comment: Так же, как вы это делаете в основном потоке.

Comment: Не совсем понимаю, о чём Вы.

Comment: Почитайте основы asyncio в любой документации. Там будет обязательно рассказано, как правильно запускать корутины. И нет никакой разницы, в отдельном потоке или нет.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо.

Comment: Не стоит смешивать асинхронность с многопоточностью без очень веской причины. Зачем это вам?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`async` функции предназначены для выполнения внутри цикла событий (`event loop`), они выполняются в одном потоке и переключение происходит, когда одна из них засыпает.

Если просто выполнить блокирующую функцию внутри асинхронной, выполнение всей программы приостановится. Чтобы этого не произошло, такую функцию нужно запускать отдельном потоке с помощью исполнителя (`executor`).

```
import asyncio, time

def slow_fn(x):
    time.sleep(1) # блокирующий sleep
    return x * 2

async def async_fn(x):
    return await asyncio.get_event_loop().run_in_executor(None, slow_fn, x)

async def parallel_task():
    for i in range(5):
        await asyncio.sleep(1) # асинхронный sleep
        print(f'from task {i}')

async def main():
    # задача, которая будет выполняться на фоне
    task = asyncio.create_task(parallel_task())

    # эти функции выполнятся последовательно, но заблокируют выполнение task
    print(slow_fn('a'))
    print(slow_fn('b'))

    # эти тоже последовательно, но уже не станут блокировать
    print(await async_fn('c'))
    print(await async_fn('d'))

    # эти выполнятся параллельно
    for result in await asyncio.gather(async_fn('x'), async_fn('y')):
        print(result)

    # и завершения task тоже дождемся
    await task

asyncio.run(main())
```

Этот код актуален для `python 3.7`, для предыдущих версий требуются небольшие изменения.

Comment: Только этот ответ не соответствует вопросу